# SphinxQL Variables Deprecated, Alternate Query?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I had what I thought was a fairly straightforward SphinxQL query, but it turns out @ variables are deprecated (see example below)

```
SELECT *,@weight AS m FROM test1 WHERE MATCH('tennis') ORDER BY m DESC LIMIT 0,1000 OPTION ranker=bm25, max_matches=3000, field_weights=(title=10, content=5);
```

I feel like there **must** be a way to sort the results by strength of match. What is the replacement?

On another note, what if I want to include in it a devaluation if certain other words appear. For example, let's say I wanted to devalue results that had the word "apparel" in them. Could that be executed in the same query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well results are 'by default'  in weight decending, so just do...

```
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH('tennis') LIMIT 0,1000 OPTION ...
```

But otherwise its, just the @ variables, are replaced by 'functions' mainly because its more 'SQL like'. So **@weight**, is `WEIGHT()`

```
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH('tennis') ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC ...
```

or

```
SELECT *,WEIGHT() AS m FROM test1 WHERE MATCH('tennis') ORDER BY m DESC ...
```

For reference **@group** is instead `GROUPBY()`, **@count** is `COUNT(*)`, **@distinct** is `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, **@geodist** is `GEODIST(...)` , and **@expr** doesnt really have an equivlent, either just use the expression directly, or use your own custom named alias.

---

As for second question. Kinda tricky, they isnt really a 'negative' weighter. Ther is a keyword boost operator, but as far can't use it to specifically devalue.

The only way I can think maybe have it work, is if negative match was against a specific field, could build a complex ranking exspression. Basically as a negative weight instead, would need a specific field for the ranking expression, so could use to select that column

```
... MATCH('@!(negative) tennis @negative apparel') 
... OPTION ranker=expr('SUM(word_count*IF(user_weight=99,-1,1))'), field_weights(negative=99)
```

That's a very basic demo expression for illustrative purposes, a real one would probably be a lot more complex. Its just showing using 99 as a placeholder for 'negative' multiplication. 
Would need the new `negative` field creating, which could just be a duplicate of other field(s)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! The weight() thing was exactly what I needed so I could pass the result on to some post-processing additional relevancy stuff.

This is awesome!